# Presorted list of entries

Tags: google-docs-api

I would like to receive from server a list of documents and folders which are sorted by title. To do this, I specified parameter "orderby" with value "title" in http request. I get the following response:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>NotImplementedException</code><internalReason>The field orderby is not supported in this request version.</internalReason></error></errors>
```

I've specified also version of protocol as v 3.0. What may be wrong?